# UseEffect() doesn't fetch my data from the api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, react-fullstack

I'm following a tutorial on a fullstack app. I'm trying to fetch my data from the API using useEffect(). I've followed the tutorial by heart and I'm stuck on this problem for some time and can't seem to find a fix to it. I've also used the
Here is the code:

1)Here is the hook for fetching the data from the API.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        setData(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, loading, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

2)Here is the API

```
export const countByType = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const hotelCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "Hotel" });
    const apartmentCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "apartment" });
    const resortCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "resort" });
    const villaCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "villa" });
    const cabinCount = await Hotel.countDocuments({ type: "cabin" });

    res.status(200).json([
      { type: "hotel", count: hotelCount },
      { type: "apartment", count: apartmentCount },
      { type: "resort", count: resortCount },
      { type: "villa", count: villaCount },
      { type: "cabin", count: cabinCount },
    ]);
  } catch (error) {
    next(createError(500, "Something went wrong"));
  }
};
```

3)Here I'm trying to use that data to render it on my page.

```
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch.js";
import "../propertyList/propertyList.css";

const images = [
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/189296/pexels-photo-189296.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/189296/pexels-photo-189296.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/189296/pexels-photo-189296.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/189296/pexels-photo-189296.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/189296/pexels-photo-189296.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
];

const propertyList = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(
    "//localhost:3000/api/hotels/countByType"
  );

  return (
    <div className="pList">
      {loading ? (
        "loading"
      ) : (
        <>
          {data &&
            images.map((img, i) => (
              <div className="pListItem">
                <img src="" alt="" className="pListImage" />
                <h1>{data[0].type}</h1>
                <span>{data[0].count}</span> <span>{data[0].type}</span>
              </div>
            ))}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default propertyList;
```

Here are the photos with the error that I get. I don't think the first one is an error but i think it might help solve the issue.
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you log the result of `res.data` when you are getting it? it seems like your data[0] item doesn’t have `type` property.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CEXpCaH.png 
Don't mind the first 2 ones, their are from another call. Also if i go into and clg the data[0] or data it also gives the same result - the first 2, but i can't access the values type and count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add null checks where you are using the data

```
<div className="pList">
  {loading ? (
    "loading"
  ) : (
    <>
      {data && data.length > 0 &&
        images.map((img, i) => (
          <div className="pListItem">
            <img src="" alt="" className="pListImage" />
            <h1>{data[0]?.type}</h1>
            <span>{data[0]?.count}</span> <span>{data[0].type}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: this worked tysm :D